# How should I model a schema in which models can be related to entities of different types in Django

Tags: sql, django, postgresql

Schema Option 1: https://gist.github.com/guyjacks/6ec4c1b0fa41b3f666f5c6adf2dfaf89

Schema Option 2: https://gist.github.com/guyjacks/4838cd76b2f924629d2a3f2ba316a504

I guess this is really two questions:

1. Which schema is recommended from a relational db perspective?
2. Is there an idiomatic way to model either schema in Django?

Cheers!

Comment: Hi, I'd suggest you share the actual code rather than links. It is easier for people to see the problem and some might downvote you for it.

Comment: Also, have a look at django's `Generic Relations` here's a good tutorial: https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/10/13/how-to-use-generic-relations.html

Comment: Ha, I was told that using gists was the proper way to share code on SO when I first joined years ago.

Comment: =) I have seen a lot of people get downvoted for it. But the main reason, I'd say, is that more people are likely to help if they see the code right away.

Comment: @The_Cthulhu_Kid Generic Relations are the correct way to my requirements in Django.  I'll mark your formal answer as the solution if you post it.  Thank you.

Comment: Cheers! I still think adding your schema examples would be a good idea. Adding them might help anyone facing a similar problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do this would be to use `Generic Relations`:

```
from django.contrib.contenttypes.fields import GenericForeignKey
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType
```

And in the model you want to relate to various models:

```
class SomeModel(models.Model):
    ...

    # Below the mandatory fields for generic relation
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_object = GenericForeignKey()
```

And in the models you want related:

```
from django.contrib.contenttypes.fields import GenericRelation

class SomeOtherModel(models.Model):
    ...
    # The relation
    your_field = GenericRelation(SomeModel)
```

If you want to be able to use reverse queries see this from the docs:

> `related_query_name`
>
> The relation on the related object back to this object doesn’t exist
>   by default. Setting `related_query_name` creates a relation from the
>   related object back to this one. This allows querying and filtering
>   from the related object.

You should be careful when using them as they can quickly add complexity.

Links for more info:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#generic-relations
https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/10/13/how-to-use-generic-relations.html